# Convert MySQL function into MSSQL (SQL SERVER) function

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm not an PHP expert but I'm trying to learn more.
Here in my company I have a "Work Order" system based on PHP + MySQL. It works just fine but now I need to convert it to use MSSQL database.
I did a lot of things and now almost all functions are working fine on MSSQL. But I have one function that I cannot figure out how to convert. That is:

```
public function check_username_1($username) {
  $data = $this->_db->select("SELECT tclients.Username FROM tclients WHERE tclients.Username = :username LIMIT 1", array(':username' => $username));
  return count($data);
}
```

If I use this function on MSSQL I get the error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'.
```

I did some research here and found out that MSSQL doesn't suport `LIMIT`. Is there something I could replace it with?

Comment: There is no limit. but you can use "select top 1" if you only need 1 row

Answer (score 0):

The shortest path is to simply change the select to conform to MSSQL Syntax:  the MSSQL equivalent for the `LIMIT 1` clause is to say `SELECT TOP 1`